# Make a twister server take initiative

Tags: python, twisted

I have a server in twisted, implementing a `LineReceiver` protocol.
When I call `sendLine` in response to a client message, it writes the line to the client immediately, as one would expect.

But say the client asks the server to do a lengthy calculation. I want the server to periodically send a progress message to the client. When the server takes initiative and calls `sendLine` without the client having asked for anything, it seems to wait for the client to send a message to the server before sending anything.

How do I send a message from the server to the client immediately, without having the client explicitly ask for it?

Comment: Keep in mind that only when you use `reactor.callInThread` is your function/method running in a separate thread.  Callbacks and errbacks too.  Everything runs in the reactor thread by default.  It may be helpful to describe the who-calls-who relationships in your code.

Comment: make a server "take initiative" : isn't it how all the Skynet stuff started ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use deferreds if you perform calculation asynchronously.
Other way if it's some long calculation in separate Thread, started by lets say deferrToThread(), use reactor.callFromThread()
(I assume we don't do heavy calculation in main loop - that's very, very wrong :))
little example:

```
def some_long_foo(data_array, protocol):
    def send_msg(msg, protocol):
        # It actually looks petter in classes without pushing protocol here and
        # there
        protocol.transport.write(msg)

    for n, chunk in enumerate(data_array):
        do_something_cool(chunk)
        if n and (n % 10 == 0):
            from twisted.internet import reactor
            # here send_msg will be safely executed in main reactor loop
            reactor.callFromThread(send_msg, '10 more chunks processed',
                                   protocol)

# Somwhere in lineReceived we start long calculation
def cb(result):
    self.transport.write('got result: {}'.format(result))
d = threads.deferToThread(some_long_foo, data_array, self)
d.addCallback(cb)
```

Thus now we'll notify client about processing every 10 chunks of data, and then finally send him result. 
code may be little incorrect, it's just e.g.

[docs](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/threading.html)

**UPD:** 
just for clarification:
missed sendLine part. Generally it doesn't matter, call it insted of transport.write()

Answer (score 1):

You can send a line using `sendLine` whenever you want and it should arrive immediately, but you may have a problem related to your server blocking.

A call to `sendLine` is deferred, so if you make a call in the middle of a bunch of processing, it's possible that it's not being actioned for a while, and then when a message is *received*, the reactor interrupts the processing, receives the message, and gets the queued message sent before going back to processing. You should read some of the other answers here and make sure that your processing isn't blocking up your main thread.

Answer (score 0):

If by "immediately" you mean "when the client connects", try calling `sendLine` in your `LineReceiver` subclass's `connectionMade`.

Comment: nope. I mean at a completely random time, somewhere after the client connects. I have the feeling twisted is always waiting for the client to 'do' something (connect, send a message, ...) before responding to it. I'll try to clarify my question a bit more.